# Azure DevOps pipeline deploying to any of selected environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that deploys the application. And I have multiple environments where it might be deployed. These deployments are *not* subsequent. Rather there is several development or test environments where features in development are tested in parallel, and potentially several production environments for different customers with different feature sets. So the advice from [Azure DevOps multi-stage pipeline deployment to specific environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231756/) to create multi-stage pipeline is not appropriate, as the environments are unrelated.

Obviously, the deployment to any of the environments is exactly the same except for a handful of parameters that can either be derived from the name (like URL) or read from the environment itself.

Also the environments will be created over time, co the fewer steps it takes, the easier – creating a new environment means just creating a Kubernetes namespace, a database and a handful Azure resources, which can all be automated, so I would prefer to have to declare it in as few places as possible.

Comment: Could you rephrase or elaborate? It's unclear what you currently have (eg post code examples or psuedoflows), what you've already tried and ultimately what you're trying to solve or avoid? The title suggests deploying into a specific static environment, the latter statements imply that you want dynamic environments. It seems so open and subjective it's going to be very hard for someone to answer.

Comment: @bryanbcook, dynamic environment. Or rather, dynamically selected – the set of them changes occasionally, but manual action is needed when that happens.